# Why does a single line span yield a taller button?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to make some fancy radio buttons and I'm getting some weird effects. I'd like to make them all uniform is size, but I'm getting a different size dependent on whether or not the span is one or two lines. I can "hack" it to fix it by adding `<br>&nbsp;` to the end of the button names for single liners, but that seems particularly inelegant.

Note that I've stripped the JS out since at this point the issue is with the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/aslum/BMbN2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch the `display: inline-block` and opt for `float:left`

http://jsfiddle.net/BMbN2/7/

You may need to tweak your other values slightly to get the buttons positioned where you want.

Answer (score 1):

The images align with the baseline of the last line of text. Giving `.genreName` an additional `vertical-align:top` seems to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the "vertical-align" css property. It's very useful in instances like this. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp - Also, "line-height" has a significant importance to the height of inline block elements. Be sure you're adjusting this appropriately.

I would add "vertical-align: middle;" to the #Action_*Adventure, #Audiobooks, #Biography*_Memoir and #Chick-Lit elements. Also, be sure to remove the height from the '.genreName' class. This will get things in a little bit better shape. I would also recommend that you wrap the radio buttons into it's own div and float them right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, is that both the span and the radio-buttons are rendered as blocks. If your span on the left side takes up more space, the radio buttons are pushed down. It depends on the browser how it is rendered.

It seems that you want them to be positioned next to each other on the same height. You should use float:left and float:right for that.

Comment: Also note, that if you float all of the elements within a container, the height of the container will be 0px. Therefore background colors won't be visible. To fix this, add one more element in the container at the very end that usually includes <div class='clearfix'></div> where the style for .clearfix is 'clear: both'. This will force the .clearfix element to look at the floated elements and then position itself immediately under them. Forcing the container to have a height value equal to where the floated elements end.